# Implicit -a in find expression

Tags: shell, find, gnu-findutils

From the find manpage:

> Please note that **-a** when specified implicitly (for example by two tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or explicitly has higher precedence than **-o**. This means that **find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print** will never print *afile*.

Where is the implicit **-a** in the example?

Comment: From the manpage: **The  -print  action  is  performed on all files for which the whole expression is true, unless it contains an action other than -prune or -quit.**

Comment: Your answer means, that the -print action is part of it's evaluation – very strange behaviour.

Comment: It's consistent behavior and not strange if you think about it. All of the options, including actions, are part of the find expression, so they need to have a "value" for the expression to make sense. `-print` is always true.